# Closed form for summation: $\sum\limits_{c_0+c_1+\cdots+c_n = n \atop c_n = n-i}\prod\limits_{j=0}^n{j \choose c_j}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I am looking for a closed form for this expression:
$f(n, i) = \sum\limits_{c_0+c_1+\cdots+c_n = n \atop c_n = n-i}\prod\limits_{j=0}^n{j \choose c_j}$

 With the condition that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n c_k = n$ and $c_n = n-i$ for a given $i \le n$.

I would like if a combinatorial argument for the closed form is provided, but it is not necessary.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have reason to believe there is a closed form?

Comment: I do.
I proved that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty \dfrac{i^n}{k^i} = \dfrac{k}{(k-1)^2} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{(k-1)^i}\sum\limits_{c_0+c_1+\cdots+c_n = n \atop c_n = n-i}\prod\limits_{j=0}^n{j \choose c_j}$.
Left hand side is a special case of polylogarithm function.

Comment: @Tanmay: is the sum over all partitions of n with n-i as largest part? Do you intend also c0<=c1<=..<=cn?

Comment: Are you serious about j=0 as lower limit of the product over j-choose-c_j ? that produces a zero factor in each product.

Comment: @Woulter: No. It there is no limit on each c0...cn. Except that cn = n-i and and sum is n.
And about the second comment: Also, the binomial coefficients are standard, i.e. each ci <= i. Hence, there is only one possible value of c0, which is 0. And 0-choose-0 is 1.
You can see my attempted derivation here: http://math.taninamdar.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/infinite.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You have small error in the derivation on 'ininite.pdf': you need Sum(j=0..n-1; n choose j i^j) and not Sum(j=1..n; n choose j i^j) as you wrote. Your recursion then comes down to:
f(0)=k/(k-1) ; f(n)= 1/(k-1) Sum(j=0..n-1; (n choose j) f(j) )
and that has closed form in terms of Eulerian numbers A(n,k)  http://oeis.org/A008292
in Mathematica speak, f(n) equals
Table[Sum[(-1)^j*(m-j)^n*Binomial[n+1,j] k^m,{m,n},{j,0,m}]/(-1+k)^(n+1),{n,7}]
or, nicer,
Table[Sum[Eulerian[n,m-1]k^m,{m,n}]/(-1+k)^(n+1),{n,7} ]
Euler's triangle is well known to count the "number of permutations of n objects with k-1 rises" and/or the "number of increasing rooted trees with n+1 nodes and k leaves" cfr OEIS reference.

Comment: Can you write in LaTeX? I cannot understand from what you've written. Thanks!

Comment: I'm Latex-illiterate; please read n-choose-j as binomial(n,j); your error was in evaluating (i+1)^n-i^n.

Comment: Basically, you expand $(1+i)^n$, whereas I expand it as $(i+1)^n$. It can easily be proved that the both (your and mine) expressions are the same.
About the recurrence relation: How do we actually prove the explicit formula in terms of Eulerian numbers?

Comment: (1+i)^3 - i^3 = 1+3i+3i^2 while your summation would produce 3i+3i^2+i^3 see first line on second page of your pdf. If I write out f(n) then I recognise the triangle (1)(1,1)(1,4,1)(1,11,11,1)(1,26,66,26,1) etc; that links to A008292; and from there, what can I say ...

Comment: Another small item: in eqn 1 you define f(n) as sum(i=1..inf;i^n/k^i) but on pg. 2 you give the base case f(0)=sum(i=0..inf;1/k^i) neglecting that eqn 1 defines f(0)=1/(k-1), not k/(k-1). Summing i from 0 or from 1 makes no difference, except for n=0.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for pointing those mistakes out. But still, the question remains, how to convert the summation to the Eulerian numbers?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13046/discussion-between-wouter-m-and-tanmay-inamdar)